# How to use TLS1.2 in Guzzle v6

Tags: php, guzzle, guzzle6

Until now I created the client by simply:

```
$this->guzzle = new Client(['timeout' => 5, 'base_uri' => $uri]);
```

The client talks to a HTTPS endpoint. How to tell Guzzle to use `TLS1.2`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That wasn't [too hard](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/faq.html#how-can-i-add-custom-curl-options):

```
$this->guzzle = new Client(['timeout' => 5, 'base_uri' => $uri, 'curl' => [
    CURLOPT_SSLVERSION => CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1_2
]]);
```